# No login box for xrdp

Tags: vnc, xrdp

I am trying to connect to my Linux desktop using RDP from a Windows 7 laptop. I have installed XRDP and this is running. Connecting using RDP client in Windows brings up a blank screen with no login option for XRDP.

I also have the same problem when trying to connect with a VNC viewer - the viewer connects and authenticates but I only see a black screen.

I need one of these options to work - no preference though. Help! (Please :-) )

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked for me.

```
cd /home/username
echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .xsession
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

Comment: I have tried this but still no luck. The problem is that I do not even get the option for the xRDP login - just a blank screen.